# Enable sound on some iOS notifications even on silent mode

Tags: ios, notifications, alert

How can I enable sound alert even on silent mode for some important events on iOS?

Devices: iPhone, iPad

iOS: 10.2, 11

Comment: Device?  iOS version?

Comment: AFAIK only the inverse is possible (muting apps you don't want to hear from at all.) What's your use case for this? Perhaps there's a workaround?

Comment: I'd like to do this. The use case for me is that there are some notifications that are so important, I want to hear them no matter what. (Specific example: When our website goes down)